# Question about Finding Area Under Curves

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have a question, where I have to find the area under the curves of $x = 2y^2$, and $x = 4 + y^2$. The equations are defined as $x$ being the "dependent" variable as opposed to the regular $y = \dots$

I seem to know how to do it correctly, however, my order of subtraction seems to be a little off. Solutions online state that you have to subtract $2y^2$ from $4 + y^2$, but I'm doing the reverse. It seems as though $2y^2$ is greater than $4 + y^2$ for most of the values.

Where am I going wrong? I don't really understand.

Comment: Are you comparing the expressions for values of y between -2 and 2?

Comment: It's the same as the area bounded by $y = 2x^2$ and $y = 4 + x^2,$ so see how it goes in this case and (if you HAVE to set up the appropriate integrals), switch $x$'s and $y$'s. Or if still having $x$'s and $y$'s seems bothersome, consider the area bounded by the graphs of $w = 2u^2$ and $w = 4 + u^2$ in the $uw$-plane.

Comment: or you can use $$y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}$$ and $$y=\pm\sqrt{x-4}$$

Comment: "*It seems as though 2y^2 is greater than 4 + y^2 for most of the values.*" Make a table of evaluations for both of these for $y=-6$, $-5,$ $-4,$ $\ldots,$ $4,$ $5,$ $6.$

Comment: @The Chemistry Guy I am sorry. I did not understand which area you have to find .Is it the one between two curves?

Answer (score 0):

If we picture the graphs of these two functions, considering $y$ to be the independent variable, then $2y^2$ is greater then $4+y^2$ everywhere outside the interval $<-2,2> $ and smaller inside the interval (note: we get the values $-2$ and $2$ as a solution to the equation $2y^2 = 4 + y^2$). So to say that: *It seems as though $2y^2$ is greater than $4+y^2$ for most of the values* is not wrong from an intuitive point of view (though the two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ we are referring to are of the same cardinality). Nevertheless, we are interested about the situation inside $<-2,2> $ and thus (I guess from your: *I'm doing the reverse* <--
 referring to subtraction) you correctly compute the following integral $$ \int_{-2}^2 (4+y^2 - 2y^2) \operatorname{d}y $$
The whole perspective changes should we have not assume that $y$ is independent variable. In such a case the situation would be slightly more complicated. We would integrate functions  as described in comments by Dr. Sonhard Graubner and the computation would split into two steps. Namely, we would firstly integrate the function $y = \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} $ over the interval $<0,4>$ and then the function $ y = \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} - \sqrt{x-4}$ over the interval $<4,8>$. Then we would add both these results and multiply by 2 (for the above procedure equals only the upper part of the area given by the two curves $2y^2$ and $4+y^2$; here upper considered w.r.t. $x$ being independent variable). Observe that the mentioned approaches give the same result which was also said by Dave L. Renfro in his comment.